# How to add two UIImageView in UIViewController using Nib file?

Tags: ios, image, ipad, uiimageview, xib

I have to show two different images for the corresponding orientations. I have added two images in one UIImageView by using Nib file. I want to show `image1.png` in iPad orientation Portrait and want to show `image2.png` in orientation Landscape mode. Can any one please suggest me how to add two UIImageView by Nib file in `UIViewController`? Please suggest any tutorials for iPad nib file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the image of the UIImageView in the shouldAutorotate method of the view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

if ( (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) && (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ) {
    // Set image in landscape mode
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
}
else
    // Set image in portrait mode
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
}
```

}

I hope it helps to you :)

Comment: Dont't forget return YES at the end

Answer (score 1):

Just drag UIImageView from the Library and place into your view.
But if you are using one UIViewController and one view, you need to handle image view rotation changes in the code. The simplest way - show/hide depends on orientation.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    UIImageView *landscapeimageView = nil;
    if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) ){
        landscapeImageView.hidden = NO;
        portretOmageView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else{
        landscapeImageView.hidden = YES;
        portretOmageView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

You can also use only one UIImageView and change `image` property to required image:

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];//or @"image2.png"
```